# Why create a shallow copy of a perl object attribute hash?

Tags: perl, oop

I found this code snippet in beginning perl book (chapter on OOP):

```
 1  sub new {
 2    my ($class, $arg) = @_;
 3    my $self = bless {}, $class;
 4    $self->_initialize;
 5   
 6    return $self;
 7  }

 8  sub _initialize {
 9    my ($self, $arg) = @_;
10    my $class = ref $self;
11    my %arg = %$arg;
12
13    $self->{attributes}{name} = $arg{name};
14    ...
15  }
```

In LINE_11, I think you don't really need to create a shallow copy of the `arg` ref. As we can simply use the dereference operator `->` to get the hash value. Is there a good reason why a shallow copy was created? Is it simply to make the code more readable? Is this considered a best practice in perl OOP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason to there. Probably someone too shy to use references.

If `delete($arg{name})` had been used instead of `$arg{name}` (to check for unexpected leftovers), that would be different.

Answer (score 1):

The author provided an explanation. I had not gotten to it before I posted the question, sorry.

Somewhere inside `sub _initialize`, some keys of the passed `arg` ref is actually deleted. The `arg` ref is then later used to print a message with a list of the `arg`'s remaining keys. If a copy was not created, this could produce unexpected side effects.